# What is the meaning of the second line of this sher?

Tags: poetry, meaning, khamoshi-shayari, urdu-language

> asar bhī le rahā huuñ terī chup kā
>   tujhe qaa.il bhī kartā jā rahā huuñ

I'm researching on Urdu shayars and it's a part of my assignment to collect 500 urdu shers with their meaning. The original link for the above lines is [here](https://rekhta.org/couplets/asar-bhii-le-rahaa-huun-terii-chup-kaa-firaq-gorakhpuri-couplets).

What I understood from first line: "poet is referring to his beloved that he is enjoying her's silence". But I'm not getting the second line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I know my language correctly then the literal meaning is:

> Even after being influenced by your silence
>   I am also impressing you.

Most of the shayaris are romantic. So I'll assume that the first person is male and the one he is talking to is female.

So, here the Shayar, Firaq Gorakhpuri, probably says that he is telling a story (or anything else) to her. And she is listening to it silently. In that way, he is impressing her with his words.